# Using one stored procedure in Entity Framework to insert into two tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Entity Framework 4, I've got two tables in my database model (let's call them `Info` and `Data`) that map to actual database tables. In the `Info` table, there is a `DataId` column that links the two tables together (the tables are always 1:1).

Important columns on the table are:

**Info**:

- Id
- DataId => Links to Data.id
- Property1
- Property2

**Data**:

- id => Links to Info.DataId
- Xml
- Property1

I wrote a stored procedure to insert data. This procedure first inserts a row into `Data` (so I can get the `Data.id` value) and then inserts a row into `Info`. It gets called in code when I call `context.SaveChanges()`.

I set this stored procedure to run when inserting is done on `XmlDataInfo` since it contains all the fields I need for the procedure except for `Data.Xml`.

I'm running into two problems because of the `Data.Xml` being in a different table...

1. If I do not set/change `Data.Xml`, the `INSERT` runs my stored procedure correctly. When I do set that value, the Entity Framework tries to do an insert on the `Data` table too. I only want it to run my stored procedure call (on the `Info` table) which inserts to both tables. I need to set `Data.Xml` because my procedure needs this value so I can't leave it NULL.
2. I can't figure out how to set the `Data.Xml` value in the stored procedure mapping. It doesn't let me select child elements for the property to use in the property drop down.

I saw some suggestions to create a partial class on `Info` in code and I can do that to access this property in code but that partial class property is not available on the model so I still can't choose it as the mapping property.

---

That's the just of my issue. I haven't done a lot with EF yet so maybe there is something I'm missing or doing incorrectly.

It seems like there should be some way I can map a field on Info that can get/set `Data.Xml` and then call my procedure without also trying to do an insert on the `Data` table. I was hoping I could add some kind of code only property to the Info model that I could get this value with, but I can't figure out a way to do that where it is accessible in the stored procedure mappings.

Comment: For a proper 1:1 association in EF. you should drop `Info.DataId`. `Data.Id` should refer to `Info.Id` (making `Info` the principle). *Or* `Info.Id` should refer to `Data.Id` (making `Data` the principle).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do here.  I think you may not have a complete understanding of EF or how stored procedures should be called.

A few things to note:
 1. Your stored procedure should take care of inserting to both tables.  When it is called from your C# code (via EF), you should not be able to tell which tables are being inserted into.
 2. Your entities should include both tables if you intend to read/write data.  If you include `Data` in your entities, EF should automatically create a property for writing to `Data.Xml`

Now, let's assume that all of your table columns are varchars (strings) except for you Id's which are PKs (ints).  Your stored procedure prototype would look like:

```
int MyStoredProcedure(string dataProperty1, string infoProperty1, string infoProperty2)
```

When you call this function from C# and then `SaveChanges()`, the stored procedure would insert the strings into your table and would return to you the PK (`int`) of the record inserted into the `Data` table.  You can now use this value to insert your `Data.Xml` at a later time.

```
entities.Data.Where(r => r.id == PK).First().Xml = "some XML data";
entities.SaveChanges();
```

This will grab the row from `Data` where you just inserted (via the returned `id` value) and then insert a value into the `Xml` column.

Hopefully this clears things up a little bit.  If you have a different structure/stored procedure, post some code samples for us to be able to give you more specific advice.